# How to make itemCount of ListView.builder equal the number of photos in FirebaseStorage?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter, dart

[These are my firebase storage images in its 'photos' folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZIzT.png)

I'm trying to stream the images that I've used in this storage into my Flutter app. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> qs = Firestore.instance.collection('photos').snapshots();
int length = await qs.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamBuilder` for it

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> qs = Firestore.instance.collection('photos').snapshots();
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    builder:(context,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return ListView.Builder(
              itemCount:snapshot.data.documents.length,
              builder:(context,position)=>YOURVIEW()
          );
        }else
          return CircularProgreesIndicator();
    },
    stream:qs
);
```